# How to deal with duplicated function code that alters parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, components, code-duplication

Say we got a `Page`-component that delegates the rendering of notifications to a `Notification`-component. The `Page`-component's render method contains the following ...

```
{this.state.notifications &&
            <Notifications
                     notifications={this.state.notifications}
                     removeNotifAt={index => this.setState(prevState => {
                         const copy = [...prevState.notifications]
                         copy.splice(index, 1)
                         return { notifications: copy }
                     })}
                     removeNotifyBy={id => this.setState(prevState => {
                         const copy = [...prevState.notifications]
                         const index = copy.findIndex((notif, _) => { return notif.id === id })
                         copy.splice(index, 1)
                         return { notifications: copy }
                     })}
            />
}
```

... as you might notice, `Notifications` require some rather large function to alter the state of its parent. Since they access `this.state`, these functions have to be defined in the parent of `Notifications`, in this case `Page`.

Now, one can imagine that multiple pages have notifications that needs rendering and so they all have to **code-duplicate** the code snippet above. As we all know, code-duplication is bad, so how can we best avoid it?

It's impossible to extract the functions `removeNotifyAt` and `removeNotifyBy` out into functions defined in, say, `Notifications.js` since they need to access `this.state`.

So, what's the react-way of dealing with such duplicate functions that you can't extract away because it needs to access this.state? I suppose I am not the first one stumpling upon this, giving how trivial of a case this is.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code from removeNotifyBy and removeNotifyBy into functions, and place them in the parent component. Then you can pass them into the child components as props.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract those functions into Notifications.js. (That is in case you don't wish to write those functions inside parent component).
Both the parent's state as will as the function that sets the state can be passed as props to Notifications component.

Example:

```
<Notifications parentState={this.state} parentStateHandler={this.setState} />
```

//Note: Ideally props shouldn't be named like this and one must avoid passing entire state object as prop, rather you should split it into props that the child component requires. However this is just to give you the clarity regarding how to access parent's state in child

Now Notifications component has entire parents state which can be accessed by `props.parentState` and you can also set Parent state by using `props.parentStateHandler` instead of this.setState